# Перемещение 2D объекта пальцем в Unity, как скроллинг

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как сделать, чтобы при перелистывании (свайпу по оси x), скажем объект переместился и чтоб дальше по инерции некоторое время дальше перемещался и останавливался. Именно по оси x надо.

```
Vector3 lastMousePos = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 touchDelta = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
bool isScrolling = false;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        {
            isScrolling = true;
            lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            touchDelta = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isScrolling = false;
        touchDelta = Vector3.zero;
        lastMousePos = Vector3.zero;
    }

    Vector3 newMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    if (isScrolling)
    {
        touchDelta = newMousePos - lastMousePos;
        lastMousePos = newMousePos;
    }

    transform.position += new Vector3(touchDelta.x * 0.06f, 0f, 0f);
```

Так кое-как работает, но инерции нет.

Comment: Tween engine в помощь, физику ради одной фичи подключать - дело такое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете поместить на объект RigidBody. 
И использовать `rigidBody.AddForce(vector, ForceMode.Impulse)`

Все точно так же как и у вас в коде, только перемещать не через трансформ, а через  добавление силы к твердому телу
Можете поэкспериментировать с различными параметрами ForceMode